# Truncated table after execution of named Query with JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I've an issue with JPA and hibernate. I've created a named query in this class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="findAllProjects", query="SELECT p FROM Project p")
@Table(name="projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
}
```

After execution of this query in this code lines my table is empty. What can be the reason?

```
List result = em.createNamedQuery("findAllProjects").getResultList();
```

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `result` is empty, or the table is empty? Do you really mean that executing this query removes everything from the table? Are you sure you haven't configured your app to recreate the schema every time the app starts?

Comment: result is empty and table is truncated after it

Comment: There is no way, your select deletes lines in the table, so it must be something different, maybe you are in create-drop mode when you launch your application?

Comment: How do I start this mode?

Comment: That's a property in your `persistence.xml`, for example for Hibernate it would be `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>`, which causes the database to be dropped and created at every start of the application, which may be convenient for development or test.